# Save Table Personalization settings - SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to save the Personalization settings made for a table. For Example, Once the user hides 3 columns in a table & saves. Everytime he opens the app, those columns should be hidden as per settings. Please provide some code samples or references if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik the smart table offers the variant managment which allows each user to define the display settings according to it´s needs: 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/associations .
Kind Regards,
Gabriel